# Open local pdf in cordova project with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've tried to open local PDFs stored in the www/Documents folder in my XCode project. The code I put in .js file is:

```
Cordova.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", "file:///www/Documents"+pdf );
```

Where pdf is the name of the file, which changes for every file. It works fine on the simulator but it doesn't work on device. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using below function to load files in childbrowser, it creates the correct local url in case you want to load the internal files:

```
function loadChildBrowser(isInternal, URL) { 
        if(isInternal){ 
                var strPath = window.location.href; 
                var path = strPath.substr(0,strPath.lastIndexOf('/')) + URL; 
                cb.showWebPage(encodeURI(path)); 
        } 
        else{ 
                cb.showWebPage(URL); 
        } 
}
```

### Edit

Try this for your case:

```
    function loadChildBrowser(isInternal, URL) { 
            if(isInternal){ 
                    var strPath = window.location.href; 
                    var path = strPath.substr(0,strPath.lastIndexOf('/')) + URL; 
                    Cordova.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", encodeURI(path) ); 
            } 
            else{ 
                    Cordova.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", URL ); 
            } 
    }
```

Comment: What should I do? Simply copy this function in the ChildBrowser.js file? And call the function in my js file like this?
'loadChildBrowser("/www/Documents"+pdf);'

Comment: make sure `cb` is initialized to childbrowser instance

Comment: How can I do it? Sorry but I'm new to js language and cordova

Comment: can you put more code so that i can check and fix into that. you can put the code either in here or in `jsfiddle.net` or in `gist.github.com`

Comment: try the function block i put in the edit, it should work as it is.

Comment: git://gist.github.com/2987628.git

Comment: copy the above `loadChildBrowser()` from Edit section, below the `pdf_manager()` function in your code and replace current `Cordova.exec()` in `pdf_manager()` with this one `loadChildBrowser(true, "/Documents/" + pdf);`

Comment: i have updated your source and put it here as comments were not allowed in your gist - https://gist.github.com/2987658

Comment: It doesn't work. This is the log

2012-06-25 11:50:50.639 prova[2682:707] Opening Url : file:///var/mobile/Applications/BFB8B759-53BF-42A9-8711-D9AAFB60E3CA/prova.app/www/Documents/02_focusxin.pdf
2012-06-25 11:50:50.676 prova[2682:707] New string: 02_focusxin.pdf
2012-06-25 11:50:50.756 prova[2682:707] New string: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/BFB8B759-53BF-42A9-8711-D9AAFB60E3CA/Documents/02_focusxin.pdf

Comment: what do you see in the childbrowser window??

Comment: It's a white page with "Loading" in the status bar.
Your way works on the simulator instead

Comment: is it `Documents` or `documents` in your project directory structure. Simulator ignores case whereas device won't so the file will open in simulator but will not work in device

Comment: I don't understand why the log says:

2012-06-25 12:04:36.521 prova[2778:707] New string: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/D7F6AD1B-7EAC-4553-9167-8FDB69FB7BC6/Documents/01_fluifree.pdf

While the directory is .../www/Documents/01_fluifree.pdf

Comment: actually the function creates a whole path based on the `window.location.href` so i think your url starts with `file:///localhost/..`

Comment: I know but I referred to the middle position of the path!

Comment: i have a test ios childbrowser application in github if you want to check the setup - https://github.com/dhavaln/cordova-examples/tree/master/ios-cordova-childbrowser

Comment: I found the problem. With iExplorer i found out that my files are in "Appname\Appname.app\www\Documents while should be in Appname\Documents. By copying these files in the Appname\Documents directory the app works fine. How can I do this in xCode withoute using iExplorer?

Comment: i have no detail idea about this but will check it